# How to show selected options only if item is selected in select?

Tags: forms

I have created a select option for Province which has values of #1, #2, #3

and I have created a second select for Municipality with values #4,#5,#6,#7,#8,#9,#10,#11,#12

If I select #1 in Province I want to show #4,#5,#6 in Municipality select only.

Can this be achieved? If so how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use [Reference field option limit](https://www.drupal.org/project/reference_option_limit) module to accomplish this 
task

> This module allows reference fields of several types to have their widgets' available options limited by the values of other fields in the current entity.